# How to Copy URI path file into temp folder?

Tags: c#, file, copy, uri

I have a file path in URI and trying to copy the URI file into C:\temp\ but I am getting an error "Could not find file (from the URI path)" If anyone suggest me would be a great helpful. Thank you.

```
public String getFile(String uri)
    {

        // Download file in temp folder 
        String fileName = Path.GetFileName(uri.Replace("/", "\\"));
        Uri fileUri = new Uri(uri);

        string fullFilePath = absoluteUri.AbsoluteUri.ToString();
        string localPath = new Uri(fullFilePath).LocalPath;
        String tempFolder = @"C:\temp\";

        File.Copy(localPath, tempFolder);

        return fileName;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use web client to download a file from a Uri

```
new WebClient().DownloadFile(uri, Path.Combine(filePath, fileName));
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But I am getting an Error: An exception occurred during a WebClient request.

Comment: @Sunny What is the actual exception or inner exception?  What Uri are you passing?

Comment: I am passing SVN file path.

Comment: Inner exception: System.ArgumentException: URI formats are not supported.\r\n   at System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)\r\n   at System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength)\r\n   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options,

Comment: SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)\r\n   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)\r\n   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)" string

Answer (score 0):

I tried in a different way and its working for me. I hope this could help for someone else.

```
private String getFile(String uri)
    {       
        Uri uriFile = new Uri(uri);
        String fileName = Path.GetFileName(uri);
        List<String> fileData = new List<String>();

        // Reads all the code lines of a file
        fileData = readCodeLines(uriFile);

        String tempPath = @"c:\temp\";

        try
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(tempPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(tempPath);
            }
            File.WriteAllLines(tempPath, fileData);
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Could not find the Temp folder" + " " + tempPath);
        }
        return fileName;
    }
```